# PyDev package explorer empty

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

Up until today all was well with Eclipse and PyDev. I have not modified Eclipse or installed anything since it was working yesterday.

Now, the PyDev Package Explorer shows no entries. I can see them if I switch to the normal project/navigator view.

If I watch the pydev package explorer and switch in and out I can see something briefly appearing then disappearing.

I've deleted every project, created a new workspace and tried uninstalling and installing pydev, but still the pydev package explorer shows nothing.

All settings are correct and I can run python code, but I'd really like my package explorer back.

Any ideas?

I'm on pydev version 3.7.1.x

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you added a filter or made top level elements working sets and have no working set defined?

I.e.:  Ctrl+F10 > top level elements > Projects/Working Sets

or Ctrl+F10 > customize view.

Answer (score 0):

This steps helped me for the same issue:
Ctrl+F10 -> Select Working Set... -> No Working Sets